# Find the angle $x$ using trigonometric identities

Tags: trigonometry

Currently reviewing trig identities but this one has me stumped. Solve the equation

$$\sin^2(x)-\cos^2(x)=1+\sin(x)$$

What I tried to do was substitute the 1 with the pythagorean identity giving me

$$2\sin^2(x)- \sin x-2=0$$

I can only assume to use the quadratic formula at this point... right?

Comment: The equation is reduced to $2\sin^2 x=2-\sin x$, you miscalculated and solving this quadratic equation we get $\sin x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{17}}{4}$

Comment: Note that $\cos^2(x) = 1 - \sin^2(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Having obtained
$$2\sin^2x+\sin x-2=0$$
you do use the quadratic formula at this point (on $\sin x$). This gives
$$\sin x=\frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}4\tag{1}$$
$$x=\sin^{-1}\frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}4$$
The omission of the other solution in $(1)$ is because that gives a value of $\sin x$ outside $[-1,1]$.

Comment: I made an error with one of the signs in my question.

Comment: @SamuelUribe Now what do you want me to do?

Comment: I fixed it in my original question.

Comment: @SamuelUribe What about my _answer_?